# change the size of 3-dimensional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have three dimensional matrix `A= p x q x r`. How should I generate other matrix which is of dimension `B= r x p x q` in matlab.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: `permute(A,[3 1 2])`.

Comment: thank you sir for your kind help

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32732553/3293881) for a *little tutorial on `permute`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is `p x q x r` then, to obtain a matrix of `B` which is `r x p x q`, we do like this:

```
B= permute(A, [3 1 2]);
```

Comment: You can also accept it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Divakar only after 24h init?

Comment: @Adriaan Yeah you would know more about SO rules!

Comment: @Divakar says the sensei with 47k rep and 1.5 years of time more than young paddawan ;)